# How can i change the Node.js version in CDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cdk

[image: Warning error]
I keep getting this error/warning when running any CDK command.

I tried changing the node version in NPM. But it didn't have any effect on CDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used NVM in order to install and set to the correct version:

nvm install 18.12.0

nvm use 18.12.0